# the first column in the time series

Tags: r

What is the first column in my `ts` output? How can I delete it?

```
ts(matrix(c(NA,NA,NA,1:31,NA),byrow=T,5,7),frequency=7,
names=c("Sun"," Mon ","Tue", "Wen" ,"Thu"," Fri"," Sat"))->x

> x
Time Series:
Start = c(1, 1) 
End = c(1, 5) 
Frequency = 7 
         Sun  Mon  Tue Wen Thu  Fri  Sat
1.000000  NA    NA  NA   1   2    3    4
1.142857   5     6   7   8   9   10   11
1.285714  12    13  14  15  16   17   18
1.428571  19    20  21  22  23   24   25
1.571429  26    27  28  29  30   31   NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first column comes from the `frequency=7` argument. It is the time 1, 1+1/7, 1+2/7, ... You can change it by just using `frequency=1` or by leaving out the frequency argument.

Answer (score 2):

It's the tsp attribute:

```
 ?ts
 ?tsp

 tsp(x) <- NULL
> x
     Sun  Mon  Tue Wen Thu  Fri  Sat
[1,]  NA    NA  NA   1   2    3    4
[2,]   5     6   7   8   9   10   11
[3,]  12    13  14  15  16   17   18
[4,]  19    20  21  22  23   24   25
[5,]  26    27  28  29  30   31   NA
```

Note that a ts-classed object needs a tsp attribute, so `x` is not a ts-classed object anymore.

Answer (score 1):

your first column is still `NA  5 12 19 26` You can get that using `x[,1]`. But, because you said `frequency=7` you get those fractions. Use `frequency=1` if you want to get round numbers as time

```
ts(matrix(c(NA,NA,NA,1:31,NA),byrow=T,5,7),frequency=1,
   + names=c("Sun"," Mon ","Tue", "Wen" ,"Thu"," Fri"," Sat"))->x
x
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 5 
Frequency = 1 
  Sun  Mon  Tue Wen Thu  Fri  Sat
1  NA    NA  NA   1   2    3    4
2   5     6   7   8   9   10   11
3  12    13  14  15  16   17   18
4  19    20  21  22  23   24   25
5  26    27  28  29  30   31   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use it as a normal matrix

```
y <- x[,2:7]
```